# Create a horizontal scrolling layout similar to Masonry

Tags: css, layout

How can I achieve the same effect as jQuery Masonry, but horizontally?   I.e., I'd like to arrange elements of different size in a brick-like layout that minimizes white space, where the container is of fixed height, and new elements will be added horizontally.

Comment: I guess turning your monitor on its side is not acceptable </sarcasm>

Comment: @John Hartsock :)))))))))))) +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the jquery plugin [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#masonryhorizontal). It allows for this exact functionality along with a very robust interactive api.

Comment: Note: Isotape charges for commercial usage.